# Is there any way to distinguish subscribers in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, data-views, sfmc-business-unit, subscriber-key

**Current use-case:** In SFMC, we have a parent BU + child BU where all subscribers eventually gets added to Add Subscribers list (shared among different BUs) which is no different than out of the box process in SFMC.

**Future use-case:** We are adding a new child BU where new industry type subscribers will be added that "may" be same as other BU (i.e. possibility of some overlapping) but most likely subscribers will be different.

**Question:** Is there any way to add any identifier in All Subscribers as a field to be able to distinguish if a subscriber was added from / belongs to a child BU or not?

What about profile management? Is it possible to add a flag something like "Added by child BU: Y/N flag" ? But, I think profile management is more focused on preference center and not designed to be used like this?

Also - when we perform a data extract from _Subscribers, is there any way to maintain the custom field and value so even data pull from subscribers can tell us which subscriber belongs where?

Comment: Did you look at custom subscriber attributes and subscriber filter? 
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_define_a_subscriber_filter.htm&language=en_US&type=5

Comment: Thanks @LukasLunow I'll check this out. I don't know much about custom subscribers. So the goal for this functionality is to determine the origin of subscribers? Parent or child BU? Is this accessible via _subscribers data view?